# React js component is not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was trying to  list all the array numbers. From the tutorial what I have understood is functions are also components in react.
I tried to create a function component and access that functional component in another component(PersonList) But while executing I got the below error.

***ReferenceError: number is not defined[Learn More]***

If I replace PersonList with NumberList, it works fine. Can you please let me know what is wrong with my code?

**Working code
=============**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <NumberList />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Not working code
================**

```
class PersonList extends React.Component {

    render() {
        <div>
            <NumberList/>
        </div>
    };
}

function NumberList() {
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
        <li>{number}</li>
    );
    return (
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    );
}



ReactDOM.render(
    <PersonList />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PersonList component like below:

```
 class PersonList extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return ( //no return in your component
         <div>
          <NumberList/>
         </div>
      );

    };
}
```

there's **no return in your PersonList** .Change it like above and [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-niwetr)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a return statement in your render method. The correct code looks like this.

```
class PersonList extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <NumberList />
      </div>
    )
  };
}

function NumberList() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li>{number}</li>
  );
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <PersonList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li>{number}</li>
  );
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```